# Declare a forwarded class definition in a cpp file, what for?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

What is the point of forwarding a class definition in a .cpp file?

Imagine that I have a private class inside another public class. I forward the definition of the private class, like class Private.

Is there any advantages to putting the declaration of my private class in a .cpp file or should I just stick with my forward declaration in my public class.h and include my privateClass.h in the cpp file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internal classes and structs are often best kept out of public headers to avoid dependencies and coupling.

If stuff is in the public header, it will mean that the public header will have to change if an implementation detail (in your private class/struct) changed. This is bad, because client programs will actually need to be recompiled (under the ODR - one definition rule) and various implementation defined consequences on class/vtable layout and or name mangling.

Once you can avoid depending on the definition of your *complete* private type, you will avoid having all the unneeded dependencies, leading to

1. reduced time to rebuild
2. avoid unintended dependencies by client code on implementation private details

A forward declared class is known as 'incomplete type' until it is defined (usually in a private header file or simply in the cpp file itself). Until that moment, only address-of, reference, pass by reference or pass by pointer are allowed.
Sometimes incomplete classes can lead to tricky semantic situations; object destruction for an incomplete type will assume a non-virtual destructor (some compilers can detect this and warn if the actual definition introduces a virtual destructor). This plays a significant role when defining smart-pointers to incomplete types, e.g. in the popular pImpl idiom. Per-use the documentation of your smart pointer library (e.g. [Boost SmartPtr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)) when in doubt.

**Update** Adding backgrounder links since this is getting a popular answer:

- [Boost shared_ptr<> constructor requires complete type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors)
- [39.11 How can I create two classes that both know about each other?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.11)
- [39.12 What special considerations are needed when forward declarations are used with member objects?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.12)
- [39.13 What special considerations are needed when forward declarations are used with inline functions?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.13)
- [39.14 Why can't I put a forward-declared class in a std::vector<>?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.14)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your `.h` files should contain only code describing interface of your module which is represented by public class. In this case a declaration and definition of `Private` class  is a piece of implementation with regard to the module interface and brings no information how to use the interface.

Answer (score 1):

The point of forward declarations is the ability to use that class without it's definition. You could just forward declare class Private, and use pointers or references to the objects of that class without including any headers or defining the class itself in that or included files.

If you put your private class declaration into a header file, then basically it's not private anymore, as anyone can include that file. So either hide it in a declaration of another class, or have it declared in a cpp file if it's at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

A class-forward is usually used in a header file. For example:

```
// Class2.h

class Class1;

class Class2
{
    Class1* m_class1; // Using Class1 type
};
```

This allows Class2.h to use Class1 without having to include Class1.h in its header file. Of course any .cpp file that includes Class2.h must also include Class1.h.

Just remember that you can declare types in multiple modules, but you can only define types in one of them.

Comment: This code will not compile, because you cannot use the incomplete type Class1 that way

Comment: @sehe: Oops, you're right, it only works for pointers. Edited.

Comment: Or references. In general, most things that do not depend on specifics like class layout, will work.

Comment: I should probably stay away from C++ questions as I've spent the last 6 or 7 years doing C# almost exclusively. Though keeping in touch with it isn't a bad idea.

Comment: don't sweat it. God knows I use SO to brush up on the details on just about every subject. And yes, I keep my non-current skills awake pretty much by the same token. It's fun to learn, and what better way to do so than by potentially helping others too!